# How to tranform a JSON database column using Glue and load it to Redshift

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, data-transform

I'm trying to replicate some production database (RDS mySQL to Redshift) with Glue.
I've had some success doing it, but I'm struggling when it comes to databases that contains JSON columns. I would ideally the JSON array to be splited into multiple columns to facilitate analysis. is there a simple way to do so with Glue?

Apologies in advance if that seems easy but i have limited knowledge of the tool.

Comment: Can you post the sample input and expected output data in your question to get a better picture of this?

Comment: @bdcloud the input would be a column with entries like '{"term": null, "medium": "cpc", "source": "facebook", "content": null, "campaign": null}' . in terms of output, I would ideally liek this to be split into multiple columns, otherwise just the same value as varchar is fine as I can deal with it in SQL or other.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check using Relationalize.apply() with AWS Glue API?

There is a sample given in AWS :
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/simplify-querying-nested-json-with-the-aws-glue-relationalize-transform/

regards,

Comment: |I've tried Rationalize.apply() but it still doesn't work. the error message says 'Unknown type '245 in column 6 of 8 in binary-encoded result set'.